# ERSPAN Type I support by iproute2

Tags: linux, iproute2

Has ERSPAN Type 1 ever been supported by "ip link add" command, which is part of iproute2? Apparently only Type 2 or 3 are supported by its recent versions: "erspan_ver version - specifies the ERSPAN version number. version indicates the ERSPAN version to be created: 1 for version 1 (type II) or 2 for version 2 (type III)." Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the time of this question, the answer would have been no. It appeared shortly after, with a [commit on 2020-05-05](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=f989d546a2d5a9f001f6f8be49d98c10ab9b1897) made available in [kernel 5.8 released on 2020-08-02](https://kernelnewbies.org/Linux_5.8):

> erspan: Add type I version 0 support.
>
> The Type I ERSPAN frame format is based on the barebones IP +
> GRE(4-byte) encapsulation on top of the raw mirrored frame. Both type
> I and II use 0x88BE as protocol type. Unlike type II and III, no
> sequence number or key is required. To creat a type I erspan tunnel
> device:
>
> ```
>   $ ip link add dev erspan11 type erspan \
>             local 172.16.1.100 remote 172.16.1.200 \
>             erspan_ver 0
> ```
>
> Signed-off-by: William Tu ...
> Signed-off-by: David S.Miller ...

This might likely require an adequate version of the *iproute2* tools.

ERSPAN Type I is mentioned in [an RFC draft](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-foschiano-erspan-03#section-4.1). As written in the previous quote it appears the difference with Type II at the GRE layer is that there's no *Sequence Number Present* bit set, thus no Sequence Number field, and then inside GRE there's no specific ERSPAN header nor trailing CRC, but just the mirrored frame.

Type II has a dedicated Ver field of value 0x1 and type III has this field set to 0x2 (as well as a different GRE *Protocol Type*). As there's no such field at all for Type I, using `erspan_ver 0` just means asking for a type I ERSPAN tunnel device. Hence the expression "Type I version 0".

Comment: Sorry just noticed... thanks for getting back. Yes it was kindly implemented by William indeed earlier this year.